# Is nested time-series in BigQuery a good idea?

Tags: database, google-bigquery, looker

I have multiple time-series, for example, for different categories and products. So my data have the following columns: time, category, product, sales. Should I just create a normal table with time partition and category+product clustering, or should I create a nested structure such as

```
SELECT category, product, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(time, sales) ORDER BY time ASC) as series
FROM data_source
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

The end goal is to visualize the data in Looker, where I would like to see the trending for multiple category and product, i.e. (number of products x number of categories) time-series.

Comment: With nested structure, you cannot use clustering for time and sale. If I don't remember wrong, you'll have to flatten the structure in your queries in Looker Studio.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the above approach, and Looker can read the data just fine, with no difference from using a flat table. However, I think you are right about the clustering. It can make drill down more inefficient this way.